# Retrieve all calculations in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

List the lowest and highest salary per city, the total number of employees per city, the number of employees earning the lowest salary, the number of employees earning the highest salary, the percentage of employees earning the highest salary per city and the percentage of employees earning the lowest salary per city.

This is the dbscheme in sqlite 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvdgnq93ci64qqc/20191001141246.sqliteonline.com.sql?dl=0

At this point I can shown city number of employees and min max salary, but I can't understand how to display "the number of employees earning the lowest salary" (I think lower than average), the number of employees earning the highest salary, the percentage of employees earning the highest salary per city, and the percentage of employees earning the lowest salary per city:

```
SELECT locations.city, COUNT(employees.employee_id) as 'Employees_Number',
min(employees.salary), max(employees.salary)
FROM locations INNER JOIN departments
ON locations.location_id=departments.location_id INNER JOIN employees
ON departments.department_id=employees.DEPARTMENT_ID INNER JOIN jobs
ON employees.job_id=jobs.JOB_ID
GROUP by locations.city;
```

I don't know how to do this in one query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1):

Query.

```
SELECT a.city
  , a.Employees_Number
  , a.Employees_Min_Number
  , (a.Employees_Min_Number / a.Employees_Number * 100) AS Min_Rate
  , a.Employees_Max_Number
  , (a.Employees_Max_Number / a.Employees_Number * 100) AS Max_Rate
FROM (
  SELECT x.city, x.Employees_Number
    , (
        select count(*) 
        FROM locations INNER JOIN departments
        ON locations.location_id=departments.location_id INNER JOIN employees
        ON departments.department_id=employees.DEPARTMENT_ID INNER JOIN jobs
        ON employees.job_id=jobs.JOB_ID
        where locations.city = x.city and employees.salary = x.Min_Salary
    ) AS 'Employees_Min_Number',
    , (
        select count(*) 
        FROM locations INNER JOIN departments
        ON locations.location_id=departments.location_id INNER JOIN employees
        ON departments.department_id=employees.DEPARTMENT_ID INNER JOIN jobs
        ON employees.job_id=jobs.JOB_ID
        where locations.city = x.city and employees.salary = x.Max_Salary
    ) AS 'Employees_Max_Number'
  FROM (
      SELECT locations.city, 
        COUNT(employees.employee_id) as 'Employees_Number',
        min(employees.salary) as 'Min_Salary', 
        max(employees.salary) as 'Max_Salary'
      FROM locations INNER JOIN departments
      ON locations.location_id=departments.location_id INNER JOIN employees
      ON departments.department_id=employees.DEPARTMENT_ID INNER JOIN jobs
      ON employees.job_id=jobs.JOB_ID
      GROUP by locations.city
  ) x
) a;
```

Comment: i try run the query on https://sqliteonline.com/ but i retrive this error: "Uncaught Error: near "a": syntax error" here a datya model picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdzbxwrwntaxb7v/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: still I tried your new query still getting an error "Uncaught Error: near "a": syntax err"

Comment: @JuSn-Lee now code work but there is wrong interpretation/results: a) is missing List the lowest and highest salary per city, b) min and max salary I think should be based on the data model link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdzbxwrwntaxb7v/Capture.PNG?dl=0  compared to table "jobs" there is a min_salary and max_salary, could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT a.city
  , a.Employees_Number
  , a.Employees_Min_Number
  , (a.Employees_Min_Number * 100 / a.Employees_Number ) AS Min_Rate
  , a.Employees_Max_Number
  , (a.Employees_Max_Number * 100 / a.Employees_Number ) AS Max_Rate
  , a.Minimum_Salary
  , a.Maximum_Salary
FROM (
  SELECT x.city, x.Employees_Number, x.Minimum_Salary, x.Maximum_Salary
    , (
        select count(*) 
        FROM locations INNER JOIN departments
        ON locations.location_id=departments.location_id INNER JOIN employees
        ON departments.department_id=employees.DEPARTMENT_ID INNER JOIN jobs
        ON employees.job_id=jobs.JOB_ID
        where locations.city = x.city and employees.salary < jobs.min_salary
    ) AS 'Employees_Min_Number',
      (
        select count(*) 
        FROM locations INNER JOIN departments
        ON locations.location_id=departments.location_id INNER JOIN employees
        ON departments.department_id=employees.DEPARTMENT_ID INNER JOIN jobs
        ON employees.job_id=jobs.JOB_ID
        where locations.city = x.city and employees.salary > jobs.max_salary
    ) AS 'Employees_Max_Number'
  FROM (
      SELECT locations.city, 
        COUNT(employees.employee_id) as 'Employees_Number',
        min(employees.salary) as 'Minimum_Salary', 
        max(employees.salary) as 'Maximum_Salary'
      FROM locations INNER JOIN departments
      ON locations.location_id=departments.location_id INNER JOIN employees
      ON departments.department_id=employees.DEPARTMENT_ID INNER JOIN jobs
      ON employees.job_id=jobs.JOB_ID
      GROUP by locations.city
  ) x
) a;
```